# Как в Android можно узнать, есть ли записи в БД?

Tags: cursor, android, база-данных

Я знаю, что можно узнать количество записей из `cursor` методом `cursor.getCount()`, но для этого нужно получить этот курсор. А меня интересует,

**как можно узнать количество записей в БД без курсора (если это возможно).**

Т.к. не хочется получать `cursor` только ради того, чтобы узнать, сколько есть строк данных в БД.

Comment: Сделать метод с запросом select count(1) from table?

Comment: Может я неправильно действую. Подскажите. Мне нужно знать о состоянии БД, т.е. знать,пустая она или нет. Cursor вызывать не хочу, т.к. данные из неё использовать не буду, ищу более элегантный способ...

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, в программировании, к сожалению, нет понятия "не хочется". Есть пути решения проблемы, из которых выбирается наиболее оптимальный, исходя из поставленной задачи.

К сожалению, всё вот так вот скучно. Сделайте пока через курсор, потом, если здесь напишут вариант получше или сами найдете - просто перепишете тот кусок кода.

Comment: Gorets. И как это сделать? Ибо запросы такого характера я не умею делать.

Comment: Etki. Я понимаю, что нету такого понятия, но хочется сделать всё красиво и аккуратно.

Comment: Вряд ли. Для того указанный Вами метод и выдумывался, чтобы узнать количество записей.

Comment: Aleksandr_ami. Дело в том, что того, этот cursor будет содержать данные, а это память занимается лишняя, а потом ещё cursor закрывать надо по "этикету" - сплошной геморой.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, через курсор будет вполне себе аккуратно. Не бойтесь большого количества абстракции и строк кода на какой-то один метод - это несколько муторно, но именно благодаря этому можно строить прямо-таки гигантские системы.

Answer (score 1):

[[@BORSHEVIK](/users/20408/borshevik)](/users/20408/borshevik) думаю, что оптимизацию какую-никакую они уже там сделали, вряд ли лучше сделаете. Тут как ни крути, для обращения к БД используется SQLiteDatabase и один из его методов, например rawQuery (как на самом верху видимо советовали). Но все равно будет возвращать курсор. Да и кто сказал, что курсор будет содержать всю выборку. Например, сделайте SQLзапрос со встроенной инструкцией COUNT.